Not able to fetch data from Render web service, fetching stuck at pending
I'm pretty new to fullstack development so I'm sorry if the issue makes no sense.
I have deployed my backend on Render Web Service.
Locally everything works but when I try to fetch from that deployed Render backend the frontend does not receive the data and fetch calls are stuck at pending. Backend works though cause when I go into specific routes on the deployed Router site the data shows up normally.
Backend repo: https://github.com/itsechi/todo-backend
Frontend repo (it’s a multi repo for now but please ignore the server folder): https://github.com/itsechi/typescript-todo
I checked the env variables both in frontend and backend and it seems to be okay. When I change the url for the local host of the backend the frontend normally fetches the data and everything works correctly. Please help!
